# How to achieve this button appearance

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, mvvm, styles

Im trying to achieve this button look with XAML, please have a look at the following link:

[image]

I already have the outlined text to put white borders to the numbers but, I would like to draw a triangle in right-top corner and also a character inside. Which would be the best approach to do it?

Comment: if you don't post any code to show the work you have already done then the best approach is draw triangle (and also a character, etc) in Paint

Comment: you are very funny mate. This is why I'm asking you, because I don't know how to do it properly in code. And yes, I have drawn this with paint.

Comment: Why make things complicated ? Use the image as button content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with doing something like this in Blend.

```
<Button >
  <Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
         <Border Background="#FF008081">
            <Grid>
                <Path Data="M320,80 L319.5,109.5 289.5,79.5 z" Fill="#FFEA1D24"  Height="31"  Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="31.5"/>
                <Path Data="M315,85 L315,93.25 C313.2803,95.392823 311.44247,95.307959 309.5,93.25 L309.5,85" Fill="#FFEA1D24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="11.421"  Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="6.5" Margin="5"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Button.Template>
</Button>
```